# Spring Prototype bean with nested prototype beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have the following set of dependent objects I need to convert to the Spring beans and remove `new` operations from each constructor:

```
public class ServiceAlphaImpl implements ServiceAlpha {
  private final Platform platform;
  private final ServiceBeta serviceBeta;

  public ServiceAlphaImpl(final Platform platform) {
    this.platform = platform;
    this.serviceBeta = new ServiceBetaImpl(platform);
  }

  // some logic
}

public class ServiceBetaImpl implements ServiceBeta {
  private final Platform platform;
  private final ServiceGamma serviceGamma;

  public ServiceBetaImpl(final Platform platform) {
    this.platform = platform;
    this.serviceGamma = new ServiceGammaImpl(platform);
  }

  // some logic
}

public class ServiceGammaImpl implements ServiceGamma {
  private final Platform platform;

  public ServiceGammaImpl(final Platform platform) {
    this.platform = platform;
  }

  // some logic
}
```

The object of type `Platform` is **not** a bean, so I suppose I need to have those services dependent on Platform to be a prototype scoped, e.a. for each Platform object I would dynamically in runtime create a service. How can I get the bean of `ServiceAlpha` type with properly initialized nested prototypes with the same Platform object by doing simply `applicationContext.getBean(ServiceAlpha.class, new Platform("OMEGA"))` or using some factory and having something like this at the end:

```
@Service
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class ServiceAlphaImpl implements ServiceAlpha {
  private final Platform platform;
  private final ServiceBeta serviceBeta;

  // some logic
}

@Service
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class ServiceBetaImpl implements ServiceBeta {
  private final Platform platform;
  private final ServiceGamma serviceGamma;

  // some logic
}

@Service
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class ServiceGammaImpl implements ServiceGamma {
  private final Platform platform;

  // some logic
}
```

I would be glad also to know suggestions on the restructuring of the current hierarchy.